# Is there any real-time rsync sample for Iaas or Paas?

Tags: azure-sql-database, rsync, azure-cloud-services, paas, iaas

We are facing two challenges:

1. There are two databases(db1and db2) in Iaas Service Cloud. How can I do real-time rsync with two databases when one of them's data is updated?
2. There are two databases(db1and db2) in Paas Service Cloud. How can I do real-time rsync with two databases when one of them's data is updated? (same question as above)

Could you share a sample if you have experience on these?

Comment: Are your Azure SQL database Managed instance?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using SQL Azure Managed Instance, you can use Azure SQL Data Sync to configure bi-directional or one-way sync between two databases. One a PaaS (hub) database and the other database (member database) can be another PaaS database or a SQL Server on-premise data (including SQL Server Express). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) you will find steps to configure it. All tables that will be part of a Sync Group should have a primary key.

To have bi-directional or one-way "sync" between 2 SQL Server (on-premise) databases please consider using Merge Replication. A step-by-step guide can be found [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-replication-configuration-peer-to-peer-and-merge-replication/).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. There are two databases(db1and db2) in Iaas Service Cloud. How can I do real-time rsync with two databases when one of them's data is updated?

For this question, there isn't a way can help you do real-time sync with two databases for now as I know.

> 2. There are two databases(db1and db2) in Paas Service Cloud. How can I do real-time sync with two databases when one of them's data is updated?

Yes, as Alberto Morillo mentioned that, you can using [Azure Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data).

Strictly speaking, Data Sync is not a "real-time" sync. Because the Minimum sync interval is 5 min. Please see the limitations:
[image]

But Data Sync is still the best choice for you.

Hope this helps.